# Content of a php variable not showing up

Tags: php

I am facing an unexpected issue with the following php code.

```
$vadd = 'settings/images/logo.jpg';
if (strpos($vadd,"settings")  == 0){
    $vaddr = '<img src = "'.$vadd.'">';
} 
$html = '<div style="text-align:center">'.$vaddr.'</div>';
echo $html;
```

When I run the code in browser, I see the following in the page's source code:

```
<div style="text-align:center"><img src = ""/>
```

Why isn't the value of $vadd not showing up? It must be something silly, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Works fine https://3v4l.org/lkTOj

Comment: Syntax looks good

Comment: seems like you don't show the full code. Is there any loop around that maybe?

Comment: I suggest that you should  show the full view of you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code i think you dont have image in your mentioned directory so its not returining any think. i have created directory and added logo.jpg and its working fine

```
<?php

    $vadd = 'settings/images/logo.jpg';
    if (strpos($vadd,"settings")== 0){
        echo $vadd;
        $vaddr= '<img src = "'.$vadd.'">';
        echo $vaddr;
    } 
    $html = '<div style="text-align:center">'.$vaddr.'</div>';
    echo $html;
```

Comment: And what is the change here?

Comment: iCoders, you gave me a vital clue. There wasn't anything wrong in the code, but the location of the image file was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this is that the variable $vaddr doesnt exists outside of your if statement. the one outside is called $vadd (without the r).
so if (strpos($vadd,"settings")  != 0){, your variable is never created.
that means the next piece of code, `$html = '<div style="text-align:center">'.$vaddr.'</div>';` is actually calling an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: where would the `<img..` then come from?

Comment: The variable $vadd has been initialized earlier $vadd = "";

Comment: you mean the ```if``` condition is ```false```?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php
$vaddr = "sample";
$html = "<div style='text-align:center'>$vaddr</div>";
echo $html;
```

https://3v4l.org/VO2X7

Answer (score 0):

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Use === instead of == in if condition it will work

(Not able to show in code, I am on mobile.. please refer
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: The strpos() is working fine, that's why the text 'img src' is showing up.